# How to randomly assigned employees from the list to 4 different groups

Tags: java, arrays, random

yeah sorry, for confusion! my business requirements are:
An Employee object that holds a list of employees and each employee has groupNumber (1-4); and I want employees to gain experience in all other groups including they own. In each group I want to see at least 1 employee from different groups (ideal will be to have 4 employees in new generated groups from different groups). Code below is doing the random orders, what should I use to apply conditions above. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
public class EmployeeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int group_num = random.nextInt(30);
        int max = 0;

        if(max > 4) {
            group_num = 1;
            ArrayList<Employee> emps = new ArrayList();

            emps.add(new Employee("Tom", "Technology", 56, 34, 46, 23));
            emps.add(new Employee("Nick", "Technology", 65, 33, 21, 23));
            emps.add(new Employee("Jerry", "Technology", 56, 34, 46, 23));
            emps.add(new Employee("Janet", "Technology", 56, 34, 46, 23));
            emps.add(new Employee("Chitra", "Trading", 12, 54, 46, 23));
            emps.add(new Employee("Sally", "Trading", 16, 64, 46, 23));

            for(Employee e : emps) {
    //          Random random = new Random();
    //          int group_num = random.nextInt(30);
    //          int max =0;
    //          if(max > 4) {
    //              group_num = 1;

            }

            System.out.println("Employee | identifier: " + e.getUnicIdentifier() 
                + ", department: " + e.getDepartment()
                + ", texh_exp: " +  e.getTech_exp() 
                + " , trade_exp: " + e.getTrade_exp()
                + " , op_exp: " + e.getOp_exp()
                + ", shared_exp: " + e.getShared_exp()
                + ", group_num: " + group_num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about it this way... If you use nextInt to generate a number between 0 and 99 (.nextInt(100)) how could you use that number to classify each employee? (Hint: ranges of numbers..)

Comment: I have a doubt that, you want to assign the employee to a random group or For the specific group, you want to append the random employees.
Do you have a group as a class or anything else?

Comment: Can't you just define those 4 groups, iterate the employees while generating a random number between 1 and 4 for each employee and then add it to the group that corresponds to the generated number?

Answer (score 5):

How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/21743854/1160106?

```
Collections.shuffle(emps);
```

Then split that in 4 consecutive groups.

This is how you can split them in 4 groups

```
    int nGroups = 4;
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    final Collection<List<Employee>> allGroups = emps.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() % nGroups))
            .values();
```

`allGroups` will have a size of 4. Each of them containing employees randomly.

Comment: I really like this answer, even more than my own one!

Comment: Thank you @Samiron!

Comment: @Samiron - Thank you! If I want to apply some conditions for groups, like no more then 4 employees in the group and employees should be from different groups, what will be the best conditional statement if, while, do while? I'm also, confuse on how to place it right.

Comment: `no more then 4 employees in the group` this is different than what you said in your question. I think its better you specify your business requirement in more details in your question. Just add a section at the end. That will be easier to give you a precise solution.

Comment: I have an object that holds a list of employees and each employee has groupNumber (1-4); and I want employees to gain experience in all other groups including they own. In each group I want to see at least 1 employee from different groups (ideal will be to have 4 employees in new generated groups from different groups). Code below is doing the random orders, what should I use to apply conditions above. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: what I understand is you want to have each member to be assigned in a different group everytime you do it. But then I am confused with what you said `to have 4 employees in new generated groups from different groups`. Anyway, I am pretty sure in 99% of the cases the `shuffle` call give you what you want, if not 100%. But to address your problem more precisely you need to have a series of permutation. I would recommend to create a new question with this requirement will be glad to help you there and accept this one if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the bound parameter of nextInt(int bound) to limit the generated integer to be between 0 and 3, as stated in javadoc.

```
Random random = new Random();
for(Employee e : emp) {
     int group_num = random.nextInt(4);

     System.out.println("Employee | identifier: " + e.getUnicIdentifier() + ", department: " + e.getDepartment() + ", texh_exp: " +  e.getTech_exp() + " , trade_exp: " + e.getTrade_exp() +
                    " , op_exp: " + e.getOp_exp() + ", shared_exp: " + e.getShared_exp() + ", group_num: " + group_num);
}
```

And dont instantiate a new Random in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate all the `Employee`s, generate a random number between 1 and 4 for each of them and decide to which group the current `Employee` has to go based on that number:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employees.add("Employee 01");
    employees.add("Employee 02");
    employees.add("Employee 03");
    employees.add("Employee 04");
    employees.add("Employee 05");
    employees.add("Employee 06");
    employees.add("Employee 07");
    employees.add("Employee 08");
    employees.add("Employee 09");
    employees.add("Employee 10");

    List<String> employeeGroupOne = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> employeeGroupTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> employeeGroupThree = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> employeeGroupFour = new ArrayList<>();

    employees.forEach(employee -> {
        // generate a random number between 1 and 4 (each inclusive)
        int groupNo = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5);

        // then decide which group gets the employee based on the random number
        switch (groupNo) {
        case 1:
            employeeGroupOne.add(employee);
            break;
        case 2:
            employeeGroupTwo.add(employee);
            break;
        case 3:
            employeeGroupThree.add(employee);
            break;
        case 4:
            employeeGroupFour.add(employee);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Hmmm... What happened?");
            break;
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Group 1:");
    employeeGroupOne.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Group 2:");
    employeeGroupTwo.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Group 3:");
    employeeGroupThree.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Group 4:");
    employeeGroupFour.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
}
```

This code does not use a `Random`, because since Java 7, there is no need for an instance of a `Random` anymore and you can do that in one line.

*This example is done with just `String`s instead of `Employee`s in order to reduce the code.*

Comment: Thank you, this is actually worked the best! If I want to apply some conditions for groups, like no more then 4 employees in the group and employees should be from different groups, what will be the best conditional statement if, while, do while? I'm also, confuse on how to place it right.

Comment: @Links that wouldn't be random anymore, would it? Nevermind, you're welcome! If you want to apply conditions, you might have to nest `if`, `if else` and `else`. Depends on the conditions, but doesn't sound like a use case for `for` or `while`. You need to check several things, which is worth a new question or looking for similar existing ones.